# With SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) or other similar encryptions, how the operator "LIKE" will work efficiently?

Tags: database, sqlite, encryption, optimization, sql-like

Suppose a database stores user chats. Often, it's required to search the content by partial words of the sentence.

E.g. *"Hello world"* and *"JP Morgan"* both should be found when user searches *"or"*.
For such queries, we use keyword [`LIKE`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/) with wildcard `%` operator.

Now if we use [SEE](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/index.wiki) or any other encryptions, how will such a scenario work?

- Will it load the whole DB in cache?  (RAM intensive)
- Will it decrypt every item first and then compare each item with the wildcard? (CPU intensive)

What is the correct way to solve such a problem without using too much on memory or CPU?

Comment: The encryption is done on the page level, so it will decrypt all necessary pages. I'm not sure how decrypting every item is more CPU intensive than loading the whole DB though?

Comment: @Martheen, will the processing required for running operator `LIKE` on un-encrypted data and encrypted data be the same? I think in case of encrypted DB, first the row data has to be decrypted and then be compared. It will be more on CPU, if such queries are run frequently.

Comment: The whole page will be decrypted, and then it will be compared as usual. So the CPU & memory overhead compared to an unencrypted database depends on how big each page is (bigger page means more to cache, and *might* means more unneeded decryption when the table itself is much smaller than the page).

There's https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/07/ibm-completes-successful-field-trials-on-fully-homomorphic-encryption/ that allow searching directly without decrypting the whole pages (or even unrequired rows) but the selling point right now seems to be more about security instead of performance